# To "levy criticism" or to "level criticism?"

Tags: idioms

In a recent [NY Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/21/us/dylann-storm-roof-photos-website-charleston-church-shooting.html) the reporter writes, "Criticisms are also levied at Jews...".  I have always heard the idiom as "to level criticism" or to "level charges" against.

Which is the proper expression? Or do they both make sense?

Comment: You might find it interesting to keep an eye on the *Times*'s [After Deadline blog](http://afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/), written by their associate managing editor for standards, which discusses errors such as this.  It's updated every Tuesday.  You could also post a comment alerting him of this error.

Comment: To be clear, this is nothing more than a typo.  It's "levelled at..."  It's completely normal that even major newspapers have spelling mistakes: no big deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just "levelled" or "level"

"level" simply means "aim" (as in, aim a gun). It's verb definition 4 in the OED

> 4 [ with obj. ] aim (a weapon): he levelled a pistol at us.
>   • direct (a criticism or accusation): accusations of corruption had been levelled against him.

This really ignorant mistake in the "New York Times" (which used to be a "newspaper of record") helps us remember an important fact about language in the English-speaking world of today:

**Standards are incredibly low.**

It's common to find on this site, questions about something which is actually just a complete editing screw-up by a major publication -- such as the example here.

Comment: +1 for the rant on standards of those that should know better

Comment: The oldest known writing is Sumerian cuneiform, a system of wedge-shaped glyphs (hence the name, from the Latin, *cuneus* for wedge) that archaeologists tell us was developed by scribes as an accounting system for commodities.  I am fairly certain that shortly after its invention, a scribe wrote a diatribe lamenting the low standards that had led to the debasement of Sumerian.  +1 for tradition.

Comment: Hi DeadRat.  Funny, but it's a very simple observation that in the US or UK, spelling, grammar, "commercial" language, novels and periodicals have drastically declined since - let's say - Churchill's day; the last 60 years.

Comment: Just how does it make sense to "level charges" against a defendant or "level criticism" against some political opponent.  "Level" means to make even, but the use in these senses means to burden with.

Comment: HL, I'm pretty sure it just means "to aim at".  Which was a standard usage for a long time.

Comment: @HotLicks going back a step, you say "the use in these senses means to burden with".  I've never seen that, ever.  The phrase "levelled at" simply means "made" and nothing more.  If you level a suggestion at Fattie on SO, it simply means you made a criticism of me, towards me.

Comment: for total clarity @HotLicks , note that (the only thing in my answer!) is literally the OED definition of "level", heh!  (It means " direct a criticism or accusation" - OED.)

Comment: @Fattie - Look at the etymology.

Comment: @HotLicks - Surprisingly I just can't see, uh, level with you on this one.  I always look at etymology, and I'm lookin' at it here.  I'm not a huge firearms user but have used one plenty; it's completely, totally, utterly obvious (if you've ever used a firearm) how level means aim (based on as you say the origin "balance") and how one of the primary common meanings of level is "aim".  Note that the many current typical meanings of the word, such as "aim" (as under discussion), "a building floor", simply " ' flat ' ", "equalize"  .. .all those meanings indeed perfectly come from that origin...

Comment: So, if I said "level" means "floor of a building" and you said "ah look at the etymology, libre", I would say "well yes, indeed, that's exactly obvious".  If I said "level" means "equalize" and you said "ah look at the etymology, libre", I would say "well yes, indeed, that's exactly obvious".  Same in the current situation!!!!!!!  Again I surprisingly just don't "get" what you're saying here; as I suggest maybe it's coz you've never been a rifle user!  {It's fascinating that "firearms" are one of those things - like say "gambling" that have been highly generative of usages :O }

Comment: @Fattie - But "level", in the charges/criticism sense, oddly means "to bring down on".

Comment: @HotLicks , I am sorry, I can't fathom that.  I have only heard it used to mean (simply) **"direct at"**.  (Indeed, there's no reason it couldn't be used regarding some positive concept.) Additionally the **definition** in the big **OED** is indeed simply the word "to **direct** at".  I have never ever thought of it as meaning "bring down on", to me it just literally means "aim at".  For me "jury rig" is a certain piece of wood on a sailboat, and "level" just means literally nothing more than "aim at, point at".  I'm sorry to report, heh!  Have never, ever "felt" the sense "bring down on".  :O

Answer (score 6):

Ignorant though it might be, the use of "levy" to mean "level" has a long pedigree. The above-cited OED has this as meaning no. 7:

7. Wrongly used for level v.1

1618   N. Breton Court & Country (Grosart) 6/1   Winking with one eye, as though hee were leuying at a Woodcocke.

a1635   T. Randolph De Histrice in Two Poems (1638) 26   Fam'd Stymphall, I have heard, thy birds in flight Shoot showers of arrowes forth all levied right.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=XjSzCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA213&dq=%22levy+criticism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5-qGVa7rCIrr-QGIjJfQCw&ved=0CH8Q6AEwEg#v=onepage&q=%22levy%20criticism%22&f=false

Comment: A typo which is common.

Comment: @JoeBlow. It is not a typo. It is a malapropism.

Comment: good one. ------

Answer (score 1):

Either "levied against" once was the preferred form, or typesetters of old made this setto(?) habitually.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leveled+against%2Clevied+against&year_start=1800

Comment: Note that an arguably more pertinent Ngram graph for this particular question is one that matches ["leveled criticism" versus "levied criticism"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leveled+criticism%2Clevied+criticism&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleveled%20criticism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clevied%20criticism%3B%2Cc0).